# Copying ranges from one sheet to another using variable cell references

Tags: vba, excel, range, excel-2013

I am trying to copy one range to another via vba in excel, however it refuses to copy anything. This is my code:

```
Worksheets("SEARCH SHEET").Range(Cells(destination_y, 1), Cells(destination_y, 25)).Value
 = Worksheets("STOCK-INDIV").Range(Cells(currentItem_y, 1), Cells(currentItem_y, 25)).Value
```

and at previous point in the code I state:

```
currentItem_y = ActiveCell.Row
```

and

```
destination_y = ActiveCell.Row
```

I know the destination and current references are correct, and by doing

```
Worksheets("SEARCH SHEET").Range(Cells(destination_y, 1), Cells(destination_y, 25)).Select
```

I know that the correct cells are set to be copied and pasted to.

Comment: You need to qualify the `Cells` as belonging to a specific worksheet, otherwise it's assumed to use the ActiveSheet, which is not what you want.

Comment: If you could specify what does "it refuses to copy anything" mean, or post some results of debugging a more granular code (e.g., assigning `Cells(destination_y, 1)` to a `Range` variable and then `Debug.Print` the `Address`), it may hint to the solution.

Comment: Angus have you had a chance to try the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

You need to qualify the Cells as belonging to a specific worksheet, otherwise it's assumed to use the ActiveSheet, which is not what you want.

My preference is to use more object-oriented programming, it will be easier to do qualify the `Cells` portions of the `Range` objects.  So your code :

```
Worksheets("SEARCH SHEET").Range(Cells(destination_y, 1), Cells(destination_y, 25)).Value
 = Worksheets("STOCK-INDIV").Range(Cells(currentItem_y, 1), Cells(currentItem_y, 25)).Value
```

Make sure that the values of `destination_y` and `currentItem_y` are correct (I would like to revise to avoid using `ActiveCell` reference), and then you can modify your code to something like:

```
Dim wsSearch As Worksheet
Dim wsStock As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange as Range
Dim destRange as Range

'## Define worksheet object variables
Set wsSearch = Worksheets("SEARCH SHEET")
Set wsStock = Worksheets("STOCK-INDIV")

With wsSearch
    '## Explicitly define a range object on this Worksheet
    Set destRange = .Range(.Cells(destination_y,1), .Cells(destination_y,25))
End With
With wsStock
   '## Explicitly define a range object on this Worksheet
    Set sourceRange = .Range(.Cells(currentItem_y, 1), .Cells(currentItem_y, 25))
End With

'## Transfer values from sourceRange to destRange
destRange.Value = sourceRange.Value
```